# Wanted to use like query in lbservices for angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I want to query all the names starting with p (case insensitive).
Below is the query object and Organisation is my generated lb-service name

```
 query = {
            filter: {

                order: 'updatedAt ASC',
                where: {name: {ilike: 'P%'}}
            };
Organisation.find({filter: query.filter})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) for this.

```
Organisation.find({name: {$regex: new RegExp('^P$', "i")}}).sort('updatedAt').all(function(res) {
  //Do your action here..
});
```